# Facebook API Integration

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate FB with my website. (USING PHP)

1.) In that I am in need to list all the groups related to my loggedin in user in my website who is connected with their FB account in it(I have oauth_token too). Also i want to allow my user to post something in their  FB group listed here using FB API.

2.) Next thing I want get all the frd list of the logged in user and to post messages/wall post to them.

I tried more in google I am not able to know whether it is possible or not. I have done only FB login integration and posting in wall.

Can any one please tell me whether the above 2 things are possible or not. Thats enough. If possible I can contiue surfing on that and make it. If not possible I'll stop surfing on that.

Comment: 1.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups, 2.) Posting to other people’s walls via API is not possible any more, because it created to much spam (and what you want to do is most likely nothing else).

Comment: If a person accepts for our application then we can able to post it ri8?